# Rails 3, how to prevent ajax remote calls (jquery) with a link_to and :remote => true with JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

So I have a simple ajax call to a page:

```
= link_to 'click me', my_path, :onclick => "if ($('#go').val() == "ok") { alert('going'); } else { return false; }", :remote => true do
```

This works just fine, I see the alert only when my field with id "go" has ok in there... but the issue is that the remote action triggers every time no matter what.

If this was not a remote link it would work just fine, not going through with the link, but it does not seem to behave the same way with a :remote => true ?

How can I achieve the expected result ?

Thanks,

ALex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the Rails UJS driver will see the `data-remote` and then perform the action because of a [function like this](https://github.com/rails/prototype-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L159) in `rails.js` so perhaps try setting the property om your link inside the JS and remove the `:remote => true`. That might work however I dont know if `rails.js` would bind to that correctly or not.

Also, consider placing this JS in the `application.js` once you're done debugging just so you dont have inline JS all over your controllers.

Comment: Yes, the JS was inline just for the example's sake. I was really hoping I would not have to write the Ajax call manually...

Comment: Its not a manual ajax call. You just need to set the correct `data-remote` on the link tag.

Comment: sorry then I don't understand what you mean ? Because if I set the data-remote manually ? rather than calling :remote => true, how is that going to change anything from rails doing it ?

Comment: Yeah set it with javascript when you want the link to be followed otherwise return false.

Comment: Not a problem we all have days like that, sorry for not being clear enough and good luck with your application.